# Product EAV Index never finishes processing

Tags: magento2, eav, indexer

For some reason my Product EAV index never finishes... Well I have left for over two days and it still says Processing... I have 42,000 products in my catalog and 92 attributes.   Is this normal?  How can I verify what it is doing?  My server is fairly meaty..

I have done a

```
php bin/magento indexer:reset
```

followed by a reindex to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Mike

Answer (score 6):

I think one 
is to set change in the database the state of the processing indexes because till there are processing indexes no other index gets updated and neither the command line works.

You can use command below in database

```
update indexer_state set status = 'invalid' where status != 'valid';
```

Then reindex

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks I will try that - however, *should* this process take a long time?  If the other indexes process in under 2 minutes each would the EAV index be significantly longer?

Comment: No it wont take much time